# In protractor cucumber, getAttribute(Value) is returning Object (browser_, then, ...) instead of returning data

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

While trying to assert the date entered in the following web page getAttribute('value') returning "Object (browser_, then, ...)" instead of value . 
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

following is the snippet of code giving error

```
expect(element(by.xpath('//input[@id="mat-input-2"]')).getAttribute('value')).to.eventually.equal(element(by.xpath('//input[@id="mat-input-2"]')).getAttribute('value')).and.notify(callback);
```

For that i'm getting the following error
     AssertionError: expected '1/6/2019' to equal { Object (browser_, then, ...) }

```
     var date=element(by.xpath('//input[@id="mat-input-2"]')).getAttribute('value').getText();
  console.log(date);
```

and the console.log for the above code is returning some thing like this.

```
ElementFinder {
browser_:
  ProtractorBrowser {
 controlFlow: [Function],
 schedule: [Function],
 setFileDetector: [Function],
 getExecutor: [Function],
 getSession: [Function],
 getCapabilities: [Function],
 quit: [Function],
 actions: [Function],
 touchActions: [Function],
 executeScript: [Function],
 executeAsyncScript: [Function],
 call: [Function],
 wait: [Function],
 sleep: [Function],
 getWindowHandle: [Function],
 getAllWindowHandles: [Function],
 getPageSource: [Function],
 close: [Function],
 getCurrentUrl: [Function],
 getTitle: [Function],
 findElementInternal_: [Function],
 findElementsInternal_: [Function],
 takeScreenshot: [Function],
 manage: [Function],
 switchTo: [Function],
 driver:
  Driver {
    flow_: [ControlFlow],
    session_: [ManagedPromise],
    executor_: [Executor],
    fileDetector_: null,
    onQuit_: undefined,
    getNetworkConnection: [Function],
    setNetworkConnection: [Function],
    toggleAirplaneMode: [Function],
    toggleWiFi: [Function],
```

Please provide some solutions for this

Comment: For the assertion API: `expect(actual_value).to.xxx(expect_value)`,  it doesn't support the `actual_value` and `expect_value` are both promise.  I didn't remember exactly, seems only the `actual_value` is allowed to be promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
const elementOne = element(by.xpath('//input[@id="mat-input-2"]');
const elementTwo = element(by.xpath('//input[@id="mat-input-2"]');

return elementOne.getAttribute('value').then((elementOneValue) => {
    return expect(elementTwo.getAttribute('value')).to.eventually.equal(elementOneValue).and.notify(callback);
});
```

Btw. Both elements got same selectors - they have to be equal.

Comment: I'm facing one more issue. xpath is having date as below.   
 //table[@class="mat-calendar-table"]/tbody/tr/td[@aria-label="January 1, 2019"].  
I want to pass the date from feture file like below 
"When enter the date "January 6, 2019"

I’m unable update the xpath dynamically

Comment: @sowjanya Just to be clear...nothing is being tested here. They are the same element so they will always equal.